# Hadoop 0.20: "job setup" task

Tags: hadoop

I am not sure if this is something that has been fixed for newer releases of Hadoop, but I'm currently locked into running Hadoop 0.20 (legacy code).

Here's the issue: when I launch a Hadoop job, there is "Job setup" task that needs to run first. It seems to me that Hadoop randomly picks this task to be either a map task or a reduce task.

We have more capacity for map tasks configured than reduce tasks, so whenever I get unlucky and have a reduce startup task, it takes forever long for my job to even start running. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop job first complete all your mapper task. Once all the mapper task is completed then it will go across the network and do shuffling and sorting and only after then your reducer task will start processing. So i guess there could possibly be some other for this delay.

Comment: The "Job setup" runs before the map or reduce phases as a separate task. I see that the job setup is randomly either a map or a reduce task.

Comment: Can you post the log how your job task is running, because as far as i know first all your mapper will get completed